# Highchart - Export data as Excel file

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can you export Highstock data as Excel? Do you have any idea?
This is my code but it doesn't work.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

$('#getcsv').click(function () {
    alert(chart.getCSV());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run the code- I see an alert dialog with formatted CSV data. What issues are you having, exactly?

Comment: iam working with iE9 and IE10. which browser are you using?

Comment: @mal2009c It's working on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

By export I assume you mean save to the client computer.  Generally, there is not universal cross browser way to do this from the client-side only.  Generally there must be http traffic from the server with a content type of text/csv etc do trigger the browser to do a download.  For security reasons it is not really possible to trigger a download of javascript generated content.  HOWEVER, you can do this, here is a great existing discussion about this.

[Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can export to the CSV, which is one of excel format.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export-CSV